# Use cookies in non-browser clients e.g Php - Android

Tags: php, android, web-services, cookies, session-cookies

How can I use cookies in non-browser clients (e.g Php - Android) in order to maintain session and other information.

My site is working based on cookies to maintain state,
Now when I am writing web services for mobile application, found out that the site is treating each API call as if they are coming from unique user, since cookies are absent.

How can I use cookies between PHP(Web service) and android application?

Comment: The android client app should be able to support cookies just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain seesion vars you have to persist the PHP-SESSIONID cookie on each call to your web service as long as you want to keep this session alive.

And also the other cookies should be set and sent manually on each request or using the CookieHandler.